# xCode #if #define iphone model

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cgrectmake

In an xcode project I use (in .m file)

```
#define embedRectIphone CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)
```

Which was fine in earlier versions.

But this should be different now as iPhones have many sizes so I need something like

.h file looks like :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebcamsDetailViewController : GAITrackedViewController <VideoPlayerDelegate> {

    VideoPlayerKit *videoPlayer;
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
    CGRect embedViewRect;

}

@end
```

Then, I call my element (embbeded custom video player) like this  (in .m file)

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        embedViewRect = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? embedRectIphone : embedRectIpad;
    }
    return self;

}
```

It does not seem to work on simulator.
Would that be possible ? Am I wrong here ?
Any other idea on how to get this fixed ?

After some help below, .m file looks like :

```
    #import "WebcamsDetailViewController.h"
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "Webcam.h"

    #define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)

#define embedRectIphone IS_IPHONE_6? CGRectMake(0, 0, 377, 210):CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)

    #define embedRectIpad CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 400)

    @interface WebcamsDetailViewController ()

    @end


    @implementation WebcamsDetailViewController

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            embedViewRect = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? embedRectIphone : embedRectIpad;
        }
        return self;

    }

    ...

    @end
```

Hoping for answers,
Best regards,
David

Comment: Be aware that what you're doing there is evaluated at compile time. So if you are hoping for different sizes when running on different devices you need to do run time checks.

Comment: this concept is totally incorrect. detecting the actual device __must__ happen in runtime not in compiler time; and you should not hardcode any sizes either.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but as I said I'm learning, not an xCode specialist yet, it's the only way I found on earlier releases to get what I had to do, all the rest went fine based on xibs for iPhone 6, but not this, and I have to send the app asap. But I will try to study your approach / a better approach for a future update.. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donn't rely on these "TARGET_DEVICE_IPHONE_6" macros. Try like this.

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] >= 2.0)

#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
```

then

```
#define embedRectIphone IS_IPHONE_6? CGRectMake(0, 0, 377, 210):CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but when I try that, I have an error calling the video player in the code I just added by editing my question. I get - use of undeclared identifier 'SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH.

Comment: Ya, sry I forgot to add few lines of code, I have edited it .. try hope it should work now!!

Comment: Thanks again !! But I still have the same issue. I know I'm not quite handling this right but it seem very hard to just say hey, I'm an iPhone X in my case.. ;-)

Comment: Have you added these lines "#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
" ?? If yes then just clean and rebuild your app .

Comment: Yes I did, and I have same issue after cleaning.

Comment: I tried in my code the same and its working fine. what error you are getting still "undeclared identifier 'SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH" ??

Comment: Nope, now, I have 2 errors, first xCode wants me to add ":" after UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ?, then it tells me - use of undeclared 'embedRectIphone'

Comment: Okay it seems you might be adding some semicolon or something in some line or in the above lines in your code, its seems a parsing error.

Comment: Can u add your entire file(.h or .m) where you are using this, then i can tell !

Comment: You can now see the .h file and all what's above the error in .m file. Hope it helps see the issue.

Comment: First you comment the "#if TARGET_DEVICE_IPHONE_6
#define embedRectIphone CGRectMake(0, 0, 377, 210)
#else
#define embedRectIphone CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 180)
#endif" code in your .h file. And i have edited my code little, just copy my above code now and retry.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that one again !! no more error message now, so it should work fine even if others seem to say my approach is totally wrong, I understand, but again I'm not an xCode specialist. I just have to figure out how to add iPhone 6+ in your logic and I should be fine. I will try other approches for a future update but I'm in a hurry to send it to app store. Thanks !!

Comment: Works great in simulators ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is completely wrong. Doing it that way, using a #define, you would *either* get an app that works on an iPhone 4, *or* an app that works on an iPhone 5, *or* one that works on an iPhone 6, etc. You won't get an app that works on everything. Including the iPhone7+c that Apple releases next year.

It is just horrible using hardcoded rectangles like you do. You should really read up on things like NSLayoutConstraint to get something that works everywhere. Have a look at what Interface Builder has to offer you. Just build one of the sample programs that you get when you choose "New Project"; they handle multiple devices with different sizes automatically, and so can you.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point, but I'm not an iOS specialist. I'm embedding a custom video player here, and it's the only way I found to get this done in the past versions of the app. I have no xib element handling this. I did it programmaticaly, and it was working great before iPhone 6.